# How to create a red minus button programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I would like to know if it is possible to create a red "minus" button programmatically. Say like

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:< red minus button >];
```

Comment: UIButtonType -> UIButtonTypeCustom = 0,           // no button type
    UIButtonTypeRoundedRect,          // rounded rect, flat white button, like in address card
    UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,
    UIButtonTypeInfoLight,
    UIButtonTypeInfoDark,
    UIButtonTypeContactAdd,

Comment: You just need to create a CustomType button with red minus button background image

Comment: Since the "red minus" button is already available in TableViewCell for editing, why couldn't programmer just call the button instead of creating a customtype button with an red minus button background?